# Exportar un .zip con php directamente al disco duro

Tags: php

Tengo un gestor de enciclopedias en php. Al crear una enciclopedia, si la quiero generar para tenerla local como html estático, se comprimen los archivos en un .zip y se cargan en RAM, como puedo evitar eso y exportar directamente al disco.
Ejemplo: si tengo 2gb de RAM y la enciclopedia pesa más de 2gb no se podrá exportar por falta de tamaño en la RAM.

Gracias

Comment: Usa shell_exec(), exec() o funciones similares (si no estan deshabilitadas en el php.ini) y usa el comando zip del sistema

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia